# instructions about structuring the application in OOP way

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to become familiar with OOP. as of yet i know how to make classes methods , inheritance, statics etc. I am making hotel reservation system (Very basic).

Problem is that i am as per my understanding implementing the OOP approach but still i am confused if i am making it right or not. functionalities are working fine but i am not satisfied with the strucure.

I made a classes database,customers, rooms
These are very basic classes like database has connect and disconnect method and a static function run(); to run sqli queries.

In customers and room class i have CRUD methods basically calling database static run() method with different parameters to perform my crud operations.

am i doing it right ? Now i have to make users for my application and also a room booking module. How should i make it forward .. I've lost what should i place in users class and what should in booking../

Basically i do not have much idea ..at what point  we realize that we have to make a class ?

Will it be ok if i made a user class and make methods login() logout() ?

I think i am not describing myself accurately but considering me beginner i thing you guyz will get my confustion point.

Thank you so much.

Example Class:

```
<?php

class Customers {
    /*
     * Declaring properties
     */

    private $customer_id;
    private $customer_name;
    private $customer_cnic;
    private $customer_address;
    private $customer_email;
    private $customer_phone;

    /**
     * View customers list
     * @return array of rows
     */
    public function View_Customers() {
        $result = Database::Run("SELECT * FROM customer");
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    public function View_Single_Customer($Id) {
        $result = Database::Run("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id=" . $Id);
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    /**
     * Add a new customer
     * @param array $arg
     * return last insert id on success
     */
    public function Add_Customer($arg) {
        $this->customer_name = $arg[0];
        $this->customer_cnic = $arg[1];
        $this->customer_address = $arg[2];
        $this->customer_email = $arg[3];
        $this->customer_phone = $arg[4];

        $result = Database::Run("INSERT INTO customer (name,cnic,address,email,phone) 
                  VALUES ('" . $this->customer_name . "','" . $this->customer_cnic . "','" . $this->customer_address . "',
                  '" . $this->customer_email . "','" . $this->customer_phone . "')");


        return mysqli_insert_id(Database::$connection);
    }

    /**
     * Delete a specific customer
     * @param int or array of ids $id
     * return affected rows on success
     */
    public function Delete_Customers($id) {
        $result = Database::Run("DELETE FROM customer WHERE id IN ($id)");

        return $id;
    }

    /**
     * Update existing customer based on id
     * @param array $arg
     * return id of updated record
     */
    public function Update_Customer($arg) {
        $this->customer_id = $arg[0];
        $this->customer_name = $arg[1];
        $this->customer_cnic = $arg[2];
        $this->customer_address = $arg[3];
        $this->customer_email = $arg[4];
        $this->customer_phone = $arg[5];

        if ($result = Database::Run("UPDATE customer SET name='" . $this->customer_name . "', cnic='" . $this->customer_cnic .
                        "', address='" . $this->customer_address . "', email='" . $this->customer_email . "', phone='" . $this->customer_phone . "' WHERE id=" . $this->customer_id)) {

                            return 'Record with id '.$this->customer_id.' has been updated ';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you give class diagram?

Comment: if i paste all classes here the question would be too long :S

Comment: @GunnerAziz please check i have pasted my one class

Comment: Your while statements are unnecessary...You could simply use $result = Database::Run(..) THEN return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/ can you use this?

Comment: yes i will try to use if you say so

Comment: i have opened this fiddle now ?

Comment: @GunnerAziz are you still interested in helping me ?

Comment: i just opened the link you gave me and i created my account there. what link should i send you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a class when you can designate a specific set of properties and methods that are present for every object of that type. For example, I work  in Web Development for a Housing and Dining Services Department at school and we are preparing for an RSVP process that is soon to 'go live'

We have a few phases, where in each phase a student is allowed to RSVP (preference) a room based on certain criteria. Each phase has the same information such as the start date/time, end date/time, the name of the phase, the id of the phase in the DB, and an array which holds even more specific start date/times for students that have lived with us (our dorms or apartments) for a specified number of semesters.

For this, I created a Phase class that holds each of those properties - instead of modifying the place where each Phase's attribute or property has changed, they will only need make changes to the Phase class and add/delete/modify the existing properties and functions. This saves time coding.

To get a grasp of OOP, read about [Enapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Comment: can you please give some example according to my project ? how would u structure if you have to make a simple hotel reservation system ? its simple a crud for rooms and customers. and main module is enter booking

Comment: Alright, lets start small. You really don't need a class for Database. PHP is a language designed to access a DB with its built-in functions (same as methods).. It would be helpful to always remember the syntax and parameters to query a DB

Comment: ok but i have seen so many database classes on internet..aren't they worth making ? how would i manage the connection and stuff

Comment: You can still create and use the general functions, I'm just saying a class is unnecessary as you now need to explicitly create a DB object everytime you want to connect. Also, creating a class will limit the capabilities when you get into more complex DB queries such as prepared statements, using functions, stored procedures etc. as they will require different types of function calls.

Comment: For example, we use a "functions.php" page (that we include in each page that needs it) that contains functions for creating and returning a mysqli connection, another function for querying the database. These allow us to very flexible in our PHP pages

Comment: ok lets say i do all with built in functions ...but then how do i identify whether to o make classes for customers, rooms, users, bookings or not ?

Comment: yes Joe earlier i use to manage all these things in functions.php page.. and that was far easy than making a db class

Comment: Well I'm not exactly sure what all of your objects will need in them, or what you are going to do with them. However, it seems like the best approach would be to create a Reservation class

Comment: ok for reservation i would have to have a method i.e enterReservation(){...} Now its obvious that a there must be a user who will use application to save reservation and also there would be a customer for whom the reservation has to be made... now should i make classes for both too ?

Comment: I would say the User info can be stored in the Reservation object, that will be what ties the reservation to a specific user. You could also place the Customer info in the reservation class (or an array of Customers and their info)

Comment: Now, if you are sure there will only be one user AND there may be one customer or multiple customers. It makes sense to make a Customer class as there will be multiples of that object. You could also make a User class and have a user as one of the properties of the Reservation class

Comment: hmm alright .. i would make a reservation class and will try to handle all things in single class. Thank you so much !

Comment: Basically, each approach is fine. It's what you want to do, it's how you want the code to be structured. Through experience, you will come to understand what is best and what generally takes more work to manage...

Comment: yes that was actually my approach of doing ...

Comment: thanks alot :) quiet clear to me